# Javamail throwing some error

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I am trying to send email through java mail. It is giving the following exception
javax.mail.internet.ParseException: In Content-Type string , expected MIME type, got null

Here is my code

```
public void sendSSLMessage(String recipients[], String subject,
                String message, String from , MailSSLSocketFactory sf) throws MessagingException {
            boolean debug = true;
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", JiffieConstants.SMTP_HOST_NAME);
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", JiffieConstants.SMTP_PORT);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", JiffieConstants.SMTP_PORT);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", JiffieConstants.SSL_FACTORY);
            props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                    new javax.mail.Authenticator() 
                     {
                         protected PasswordAuthentication                   

                      getPasswordAuthentication() {
                            return new   
                         PasswordAuthentication("support@jiffie.in", "support@1234$");
                        }
                    });

            session.setDebug(debug);
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            InternetAddress addressFrom = new InternetAddress(from);
            msg.setFrom(addressFrom);

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[recipients.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(recipients[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);
            msg.setSubject(subject);


            // This mail has 2 part, the BODY and the embedded image
             MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");

             // first part (the html)
             BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

             messageBodyPart.setContent(message, "text/html");
             // add it
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

             // second part (the image)
             messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
             String name = "logo.png";
            DataSource fds= (DataSource) JiffieApplicationContext.class.getResourceAsStream(name);

             messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
             messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<logo>");

             // add image to the multipart
             multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

             // put everything together
             msg.setContent(multipart);
             // Send message
             Transport.send(msg);
             System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");}
```

The complete stack trace is

```
javax.mail.internet.ParseException: In Content-Type string <null>, expected MIME type, got null
at javax.mail.internet.ContentType.<init>(ContentType.java:95)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1435)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1125)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.updateHeaders(MimeMultipart.java:515)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.updateHeaders(MimeBodyPart.java:1458)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.updateHeaders(MimeMessage.java:2190)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.saveChanges(MimeMessage.java:2151)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:123)
at com.markEffy.aggregator.util.EmailAgent.sendSSLMessage(EmailAgent.java)
at com.markEffy.aggregator.util.EmailAgent.sendMail(EmailAgent.java)
at com.markEffy.aggregator.web.RetrievePasswordAction.sendPasswordToEmail(RetrievePasswordAction.java)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:450)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:289)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:252)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.DeprecationInterceptor.intercept(DeprecationInterceptor.java:41)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:256)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:167)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:265)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:254)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:191)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:73)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:91)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:252)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:139)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:193)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

javax.mail.internet.ParseException: In Content-Type string , expected MIME type, got null

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: could you mark the line which is throwing the error?

Comment: Sir It is giving exception on Transport.send(msg)  line

Comment: I have found the reason. DataSource fds is null. Can you please tell me how to read image from relative path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, clean up all these [common mistakes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

JiffieApplicationContext.class.getResourceAsStream is going to return an InputStream.  I don't know how you're casting that to a DataSource, but that's not going to work.  You might be able to use getResource along with a URLDataSource:

```
DataSource fds = new URLDataSource(JiffieApplicationContext.class.getResource(name);
```